# Tensorflow Hub Directory not found when caching modules

Tags: tensorflow, pre-trained-model

I have tf 1.8 installed and running on a virtualenv. I'm running a training pipeline that loads inception v3 from the tfhub and retrains the softmax (almost identical workflow as the flowers example (https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_retraining). 
Tensorflow hub is also installed on the same virtual env.

This is the error I'm getting.

```
INFO:tensorflow:Looking for images in 'moonflowers'
INFO:tensorflow:Looking for images in 'sunflowers'
INFO:tensorflow:Using /var/folders/z1/nty40mjd64b1xwvw_l1vhcs40000gn/T/tfhub_modules to cache modules.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/X/example_code/flower_trainer/imb_model.py", line 1355, in <module>
    tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
  File "/Users/X/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 126, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "/Users/X/example_code/flower_trainer/imb_model.py", line 1039, in main
    module_spec = hub.load_module_spec(FLAGS.tfhub_module)
  File "/Users/X/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_hub/native_module.py", line 103, in load_module_spec
    module_def_proto.ParseFromString(f.read())
  File "/Users/X/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 120, in read
    self._preread_check()
  File "/Users/X/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 80, in _preread_check
    compat.as_bytes(self.__name), 1024 * 512, status)
  File "/Users/X/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 519, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: /var/folders/z1/nty40mjd64b1xwvw_l1vhcs40000gn/T/tfhub_modules/11d9faf945d073033780fd924b2b09ff42155763/tfhub_module.pb; No such file or directory
```

Anyone come across a similar problem or have any guidance on how to tackle this one?

Comment: I just found a workaround. By explicitly setting the cache folder as an environment variable, this seems to fix the issue. os.environ['TFHUB_CACHE_DIR']= some path

Answer (score 7):

A solution that worked for me:

Delete the tfhub_modules folder and it's contents. In the trace back above this would be:

```
/var/folders/z1/nty40mjd64b1xwvw_l1vhcs40000gn/T/tfhub_modules
```

Other systems may vary. For my setup it was:

```
/var/folders/cc/0dttrmf90g777cws2m3sfvvr0000gp/T/tfhub_modules
```

Then rerun retrain.py

It will redownload the trained network and should then work.